# How and Where can I easily pull data for the Dow 30?

Tags: yahoo-finance, market-indexes, online-data-source, yield, spreadsheet

Where/How can I pull the following data on the DJIA stocks into Excel from the Web that updates every time I hit refresh in Excel?

The data:
1. Last 12 months of dividend payments
2. Prices
3. DJIA divisor

I'm creating a spreadsheet that will constantly calculate the dividend yield of the DJIA.  I know where I can find this number (yahoo!finance), but I need to calculate it for myself.

Thank you!

Comment: http://exceltrader.net/714/stock-dividend-data-downloader/ looks like it might help.

Comment: Maybe this is interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097382/bloomberg-open-api

Answer (score 2):

The current Dow divisor is in [Historical Divisor Changes](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/files/djia-history-divisor.pdf).

The OpenOffice [GetQuote](http://getquote-tedsoft.blogspot.com/p/about.html) function offers fields for current dividend either in dollars or yield.

Comment: Excellent.  Do you have the link to the cme page that goes to that pdf?  I want it to make sure it's the most recent version.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3022-djiahourly.html real time divisor

Comment: Sweet, that last link you gave me was what I found too.  It's much easier than the cme site or the djia site.